# About fermionic particles and bosonic particles in RQFT, ST

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, fermions, point-particles

In relativistic quantum field theory, we can observe that the Dirac equation is a square root of Klein-Gordon equation. But, we can get the Dirac equation by defining Dirac spinor as $(1/2,0)\oplus(0,1/2)$ representation of $\mathrm{Spin}(3,1)$ like Klein-Gordon equation and Maxwell action (Weinberg, Schwartz). So, I have a question.

> Why must Dirac operator be a square root of Klein Gordon operator? Is there a fundamental reason?

Weakly,

> Why do the fermionic particles admit first order partial differential
>   equation even though the bosonic particles admit second order partial
>   differential equations? Is there a fundamental reason?

---

This is a simple question.

> Why do people think the relativistic quantum field theory is the theory of **point particle**? Is there a formalism which I can get whole quantum field theory from point-particle action (einbein field formalism)?

---

In bosonic string theory, we can only have the bosonic states from Polyakov action.

> Is there a principle which includes the fermionic states like 'prinicple of string' without supersymmetry naturally?

---

If we quantize the point-particle action (einbein field formalism), we can get the state of spin-$0$ particles only unlike Polyakov action.

> Why?

---

I want the fundamental reasons what we called 'higher perspective'.

Comment: LPT: ask *one* question per post.

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm worried about posting too much questions.

Answer (score 0):

- Dirac equation is an equation for the relativistic quantum ave function of a single electron.\
- we shall regard the dirac wave function as a field, which will subsequently be quantized along with the electromagnetic field.\
- On quantisation, the electromagnetic fields $ A_{\mu}(x) $, $ F_{\mu}\nu $ become spece and time dependent operators, the dirac fields $ \psi(x) $ also.\
  Dirac invented his equation in seeking to make Schrodinger equation for an electron compatible with special relativity.  $ i\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = H\psi $
  to sewre a symmetry between spacetime, dirac postulated the hamiltonian for a free electron to be of the form:\
  \begin{equation}
  H_{D} = \alpha.p + \beta m = -i\alpha .\nabla + \beta m
  \end{equation}
  where $ m $ is the mass of the electron, $ p $ its momentum,\
  \begin{equation}
  \alpha = (\alpha_{1}, \alpha _{2}, \alpha_{3})  
  \end{equation}
  Thus, $ \alpha_{1} $, $ \alpha_{2} $, $ \alpha_{3} $ and $ \beta $ are matrices. $ \psi $ is a column vector, and the Schr¨odinger equation becomes the multicomponent 
  \begin{equation}
  ( i\frac{\partial}{\partial t} + i\alpha \nabla - \beta m)\psi = 0
  \end{equation}
  If this equation is to describe a free electron of mass m, its solutions should also
  satisfy the Klein–Gordon equation. Multiplying by the operator\
  $ ( i\frac{\partial}{\partial t} - i\alpha \nabla + \beta m)\psi $ we get:
  \begin{equation}
  \left[ - \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}} + \sum_{i < j}(\alpha_{i}\alpha_{j} + \alpha_{j}\alpha_{i})\partial_{i}\partial_{j} + im\sum_{i}(\alpha_{i}\beta + \beta\alpha_{i})\partial_{i} -\beta^{2}m^{2}\right]\psi = 0
  \end{equation}
  \textbf{Note:} for particle with mass m and spin zero we find that:\
  $ (\alpha_{i}\alpha_{j} + \alpha_{j}\alpha_{i}) = 0 $ , $ i \neq j  $ \
  $ (\alpha_{i}\beta + \beta\alpha_{i}) = 0 $\
  $ \beta^{2} = 1 $, $ \alpha_{1}^{2} = \alpha_{2}^{2} = \alpha_{3}^{2} = 1 $\
  Then the last Dirac equation becomes identical to the Klien-Gordon equation\
  Dirac equations are satisfied by the set of $ 2 \times 2 $ Pauli spin matrices 
  \begin{equation}
   \sigma = (\sigma^{1}, \sigma^{2}, \sigma^{3}) , where:\\
  \end{equation}
  $ \sigma^{1} = $
  $                              
  \begin{pmatrix}             
  0 & 1\\                        
  1 & 0 \\                       
  \end{pmatrix}                 
  $
  $ \sigma^{2} = $
  $
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & - i\\
  i & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix}
  $
  $ \sigma^{3} = $
  $
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 &  0\\
  0 & - 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}
  $
  $ \sigma^{0} = $
  $
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 &  0\\
  0 &  1\\
  \end{pmatrix}
  $
  \
  \
  We now represent the $ \alpha^{i} $ and $ \beta $ by $ 4 \times 4 $ matrices, shall use the so-called chiral representation:\
  \
  $ \alpha^{i} = $
  $
  \begin{pmatrix}
  - \sigma^{i} &  \textbf{0}\\
  \textbf{0} &    \sigma^{i}\\
  \end{pmatrix}
  $
  $ \beta = $
  $
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \textbf{0} &  \sigma^{0}\\
  \sigma^{0} &  \textbf{0}
  \end{pmatrix}
  $
  $ I^{0} = $
  $
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \sigma^{0} &  \textbf{0}\\
  \textbf{0} &    \sigma^{0}\\
  \end{pmatrix}
  $
  $ \textbf{0} = $
  $
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 &  0\\
  0 &  0\\
  \end{pmatrix}
  $
  \
  Dirac equation has signification of relativistic Schr\"{o}dinger equation, the solutions of Dirac equation represent by wave function $ \psi $ which is a fourcomponent column matrix, where exist ‘negative energy’ solutions, which Dirac interpreted as antiparticles.\

Comment: Sorry, I want deep reasons.  I know how I get Dirac equation in RQM. But, I want the reason why it operates.

Comment: can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

Look, Klein-Gordon equation drive from Schr¨odinger equation but it relativistic case for particle with mass m and spin zero, the different is the Hamiltonian, we replace the Hamiltonian in Schr¨odinger equation by Hamiltonian in relativistic case, so this Hamiltonian becomes quadri-dimensional vector $\P^{\mu}$.
you know that Schr¨odinger equation is second order partial so the bosons characterized by Klein-Gordon remain second order partial differential.
due to the Einstein equation of energy $ E^{2} = p^{2} + m^{2}$ that give negative solution, Dirac interprated this nigative solution by the existence of **anti-matter** and proposed new Hamiltonian H = p + m. without the squar so from this Hamiltonian the equation  characterized the fermion seem as first   order partial differential. **you must understand the role of spin** in solution of dirac equation because dirac us Schr¨odinger equation that study the electron but with his new Hamiltinian. the photon as boson can separat to electron and positron (matter and anti-matter), Dirac do just this separation for the Hamiltonian to find two equation one of electron(matter) the other for positron(anti-matter).
by other side the fermions enter in the frame of U(1) transformation, you see that the solution of dirac equation give a vector (one colon).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is from my lecture in QFT, I hope that you find what you ask
\subsection{Dirak equation solution}
Thus, we solve the Dirac equation by consider that $ p_{\mu} $ is the four momentum that satisfies the relativistic energy-momentum relation
\begin{equation}
p^{\mu}p_{\mu}  =  m^{2} 
\end{equation}
if we take 
\begin{equation}
p_{\mu} = (E, \textbf{p}) 
\end{equation}
we find two solutions : one concerns positive energy and the other concerns negative energy, 
\begin{equation}
p^{\mu}p_{\mu}  = m^{2} 
\end{equation}
then 
\begin{equation}
E = \pm\sqrt{m^{2} + \textbf{p}^{2}} 
\end{equation}
\
We express the solutions to Dirac equation with two independent solutions, for a free fermion the wavefunction is the product of a plane wave and a Dirac spinor $ u(p) $ and ( $ v(p) $ for antiparticle), thus 
$ \Psi(x^{\mu}) $ = $ u(p^{\mu})e^{-ipx} $:
Substituting the fermion wavefunction, ψ, into the Dirac equation:\
\begin{equation}
(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m)u(p) = 0
\end{equation}
For a particle at rest, $ p $ = 0, we find the following equations:
\begin{equation}
(i\gamma^{0}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} - m)\Psi = (\gamma^{0} E - m)u = 0
\end{equation}
So we write:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
m & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & m & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & - m & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & - m\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
$
u = Eu 
$

The eigenvalues are: $ E_{+} = m $ (twice) and $ E_{-} = - m $ (twice), unit[nat],
The solutions are four eigenspinors:\

$ u^{1} $
$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
$ u^{2} $
$
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
$ u^{3} $
$
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
$ u^{4} $
$
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

and the associated wavefunctions of the fermions are:\
- for positive energy : $ \psi^{1} = e^{-imt}u^{1} $ and $ \psi^{2} = e^{-imt}u^{2} $ \
- for negative energy : $ \psi^{3} = e^{imt}u^{3} $ and $ \psi^{4} = e^{imt}u^{4} $\
Note that the spinors are $ 1 \times 4 $ column matrices, and that there are four possible states. The spinors are, however, not four-vectors: the four components do not represent t, x, y, z. The four components are a suprise: we would expect only two spin states for a spin $ - \frac{1}{2} $ fermion Note also the change of sign in the exponents of the plane waves in the states $ \psi^{3} $ and $ \psi^{4} $. The four solutions in equations (5.24) and (5.25) describe two different spin states ($ \uparrow $ and $  \downarrow $) with $ E = m $, and two spin states with $ E = −m < 0 $.\
\textbf{Negative Energy Solutions and Antimatter:}\
To describe\textit{ the negative energy states}, Dirac postulated that an electron in a positive energy state is produced from the vacuum accompanied by a \textit{hole} with \textit{negative energy}. The hole corresponds to a physical antiparticle, the positron, with charge $ + e $. Another interpretation (Feynman-St\"{u}ckelberg) is that the $ E = − m $ solutions can \textit{either} describe a negative energy particle which propagates \textit{backwards} in time, or a positive energy antiparticle propagating \textit{forward} in time:
\begin{equation}
e^{-i\left[(-E)(-t)-(-p)(-x)\right]} = e^{-i[Et - Px]}
\end{equation}
For a moving particle, $ p \neq 0 $ the Dirac equation becomes (using (5.13) and (5.17)):\
$ (\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu} - m) $
$
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{A}\\
u_{B}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
$ = $
$
\begin{pmatrix}
E - m & -\sigma p\\
\sigma p & - E - m\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
$
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{A}\\
u_{B}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
$ = 0 $
\
Note that: $ \gamma^{\mu} = \gamma^{0} + \gamma^{i} $,
$ u^{1,2,3,4} = $
$
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{A}\\
u_{B}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
\
The equations for:\ 
$ u_{A} = $ 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
or 
$ u_{A} = $ 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
and
$ u_{B} = $ 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
or 
$ u_{B} = $ 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
are coupled:\
\begin{equation}
u_{A} = \frac{\sigma p}{E - m}u_{B}
u_{B} = \frac{\sigma p}{E + m}u_{A}
\end{equation}
$ p\sigma = p_{x}\sigma^{1} + p_{y}\sigma^{2} + p_{z}\sigma^{3} $\
So, We showe the four solution of Diarc equation :\
For 
$ u_{A} = $ 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
we find
$ u^{1} = $ 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
\frac{p_{z}}{E + m}\\
\frac{p_{x} + ip_{y}}{E + m}
\end{pmatrix}
$
\
For
$ u_{A} = $ 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
we find
$ u^{2} = $ 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
\frac{p_{x} - ip_{y}}{E + m}\\
\frac{- p_{z}}{E + m}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
\
\
These two solutions $ u^{1} $ and $ u^{2} $ describe an electron of\ \textit{positive} energy $ E = + \sqrt{m^{2} + p^{2}} $, and momentum p\
\
For
$ u_{B} = $ 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
we find
$ u^{3} = $ 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{- p_{z}}{E + m}\\
\frac{- p_{x} - ip_{y}}{- E + m}\\
1\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
\
For
$ u_{B} = $ 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
we find
$ u^{4} = $ 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{- p_{x} + ip_{y}}{- E + m}\\
\frac{p_{z}}{- E + m}\\
0\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
\
One these two solutions $ u^{3} $ and $ u^{4} $ describe positron of \textit{negative} energy $ E = - \sqrt{m^{2} + p^{2}} $, and momentum p.\
Now we can change the spinors $ u^{4}(-p) = v^{1}(p) $ and  $ u^{3}(-p) = v^{2}(p) $
to discribe antiparticule with positive energy
\
$ v^{2}(p) = u^{3}(-p) $ 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{ p_{z}}{E + m}\\
\frac{p_{x} + ip_{y}}{ E + m}\\
1\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
and
$ v^{1} = u^{4} $ 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{p_{x} - ip_{y}}{E + m}\\
\frac{- p_{z}}{E + m}\\
0\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$
\
- For a fermion with momentum p along the z-axis,describes a spin-up fermion by
\begin{equation}
 \psi = e^{-ipx}u^{1}(p^{\mu})
\end{equation}
 And describes a spin-down fermion by
\begin{equation}
 \psi = e^{-ipx}u^{2}(p^{\mu}) 
\end{equation}
- For an antifermion with momentum p along the z-axis, we describes a spin-up antifermion by:
\begin{equation}
\psi = v^{1}(p^{\mu})e^{- ipx} = u^{4}(-p^{\mu})e^{i(-p)}
\end{equation}
And we describes a spin-down antifermion by:
\begin{equation}
\psi = v^{2}(p^{\mu})e^{- ipx} = u^{3}(-p^{\mu})e^{i(-p)}
\end{equation} 
\subsection{Fermion currents}
To describe fermion current, first we define the Dirac adjoint,as
\begin{equation}
 \Psi = \Psi^{+}\gamma^{0} = (\Psi^{1}, \Psi^{2}, -\Psi_{3}^{*}, -\Psi_{4}^{*}) 
\end{equation}
and the Dirac Lagrangian can be written as 
\begin{equation}
L_{D} = \Psi(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m)\Psi
\end{equation}
using the Noether theorem, the four-vector fermion current: is 
\begin{equation}
j^{\mu} = \Psi\gamma^{\mu}\Psi = (\Psi\gamma^{0}\Psi, \Psi\gamma^{i}\Psi) = (\rho, \overrightarrow{j})
\end{equation}